# React native error of Check the render method of App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function, fonts, expo

I am making a react native app and now was trying to put a downloaded font and I keep getting this check the render method of app error and then underneath it, it says this

> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

I have looked at similar questions and non of their solutions fix my problem so I got out of their solutions that it is an import or export error but all of my stuff is correctly imported and exported so I do not know what the issue is anymore.This is what my current code looks like

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import AppLoading from 'expo';

const getFonts = () => 
   Font.loadAsync({
    "Alef-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Alef-Bold.ttf")
  })


export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if(fontsLoaded){
    return (
      <View>
        <Home />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the Home component

```
    import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

function Home() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Welcome to the home page</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 50,
    },
    titleText: {
        fontFamily: "Alef-Bold",
    }
})

export default Home
```

So how can I solve this please?.

Comment: Can you please post what’s the exact error you are getting?

Comment: This is the first error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and
named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.  I do not have enough characters left to outpu the rest of the error so I have updated the question

Comment: Your `AppLoading` import is wrong, you have to import it like this `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';`

Comment: @KartikeyVaish this error gives me this error undefined Unable to resolve module expo-app-loading from C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\projekten\gamezone\App.js: expo-app-loading could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  3 | import * as Font from 'expo-font';
  4 | import Home from './screens/Home';
> 5 | import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'

Comment: You have to install App loading like this `expo install expo-app-loading` See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of loading font is wrong, also your imports. To correct this simply follow these steps

[Click here to see Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading)

Firstly install AppLoading like this

```
expo install expo-app-loading
```

Create a folder called `hooks` where you `App.js` is located.

Inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js` paste this code

`useFonts.js`

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Alef-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/Alef-Bold.ttf'),
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

Then in your `App.js` paste this code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import Home from './screens/Home';
import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts(); // We have to await this call here
  };

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
        onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Home />
    </View>
  );
}
```

And your `Home.js` should look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

function Home() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Welcome to the home page</Text>
      <Text style={styles.normalText}>This text is in normal font</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 50,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    color: 'red',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontFamily: 'Alef-Bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  normalText: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

By following this way of loading fonts, your `App.js` will be neat and clean. I use this way in all of my projects

Comment: Hey man now I am getting this error None of these files exist:
  *hooks\useFonts\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  3 | import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
  4 | import Home from './screens/Home';
> 5 | import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';  which is strange because I have created the hooks folder and the useFonts file and put your code in there exactly as you wrote it

Comment: Check whether all folders as well as files names are correct or not. Also make sure that the hooks folder is created exactly where your `App.js` is located. Check whether you Home component's file name is `Home.js` or `HomeScreen.js` Check the working implementation on the link that I gave

Comment: Thank you very much bro for your time much appreciated It's now working but there is one more problem, when I add another font it throws this error 
fontFamily "Airstream" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.                                           This is the updated version you can check on the expo I saved https://snack.expo.io/bnTQsONgl

Comment: You will have to upload `Airstream.ttf` in fonts folder then it will work